# 3d matrix multiplication into multiple 2d matrix multiplications

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two 3d matrices `X` and `Y` both of which have the shape `(5, 1825, 77)`. I'd like to do five 2d matrix multiplications, i.e., `X[i, :, :]@Y[i, :, :].T` without using a for loop. Is there a way to do this in numpy?

Comment: `np.tensordot` and `np.einsum` should probably help. But I do not expect any speed up from not using loops. BLAS calls are far more likely to be the expensive part (the loop and Numpy overhead should introduce an overhead of only few dozens of microseconds at most).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Ah I see. So I guess using a for loop won't be too bad then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting for those (like me) who try to avoid for loops at any cost:

```
shape = 5, 1825, 77
X = np.random.random(shape)
Y = np.random.random(shape)

p_for = np.empty((shape[0], shape[1], shape[1]))
for i in range(shape[0]):
    p_for[i] = X[i] @ Y[i].T

p_matmul = X @ np.moveaxis(Y, -1, 1)
assert np.allclose(p_for, p_matmul)

p_einsum = np.einsum("ijk,ilk->ijl", X, Y)
assert np.allclose(p_for, p_einsum)
```

The tree methods produce the same result, but, as @JérômeRichard points out:

```
%%timeit
prod = np.empty((shape[0], shape[1], shape[1]))
for i in range(5):
    prod[i] = X[i, :, :] @ Y[i, :, :].T
50.4 ms ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit X @ np.moveaxis(Y, -1, 1)
115 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.einsum("ijk,ilk->ijl", X, Y)
544 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Wow, there is no speedup whatsoever with `np.einsum` which is interesting.